# Terraform: Render special characters from typical query string (like '=', '&') in a variable assignment

Tags: terraform

It seems that Terraform is either rendering the intended query string value "... = ..", with &#61, which messes up the URL call.

I tried to escape the `\=` in the string assignment, and errors, with 'The symbol "=" is not a valid escape sequence selector'.

I also tried `format("%s %s %s", "...", "=", "....")`.  Same rendering with &#61.

Any ideas?  Newbie, here with terraform.
Thanks, in advance.